# How do I create a colormap plot that can make a sphere in matplotlib 3d look like half i bright (look like the earth is illuminated on one side)

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot, 3d

I am trying to create a 3D sphere in matplotlib and have it color like one side of the sphere is illuminated by the sun.

I have tried using matplotlib colormaps.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import cm
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.set_axis_off()
phi = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi, 50)
theta = np.linspace(0, np.pi, 25)
x=np.outer(np.cos(phi), np.sin(theta))
y=np.outer(np.sin(phi), np.sin(theta))
z=np.outer(np.ones(np.size(phi)), np.cos(theta))
PHI=np.outer(phi,np.ones(np.size(theta)))
THETA=np.outer(np.ones(np.size(phi)),theta)
data = PHI/np.pi
norm = plt.Normalize(vmin=data.min(), vmax=data.max()) 
surface=ax.plot_surface(x, y, z, cstride=1, rstride=1, 
                        facecolors=cm.jet(norm(data)))
surface=ax.plot_surface(x, y, z, cstride=1, rstride=1, 
                        facecolors=cm.binary(norm(data)),cmap=plt.get_cmap('jet'))
plt.show()
```

I am expecting a sphere that looks something like this:
[Or basically something that looks like the earth with the day side and the night side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u7ABk.png)

But instead my results are something like this:
[current plot from the above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iPQDv.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use LightSource package:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import cm
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib.colors import LightSource

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.set_axis_off()
phi = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi, 100)
theta = np.linspace(0, np.pi, 50)
x=np.outer(np.cos(phi), np.sin(theta))
y=np.outer(np.sin(phi), np.sin(theta))
z=np.outer(np.ones(np.size(phi)), np.cos(theta))
PHI=np.outer(phi,np.ones(np.size(theta)))
THETA=np.outer(np.ones(np.size(phi)),theta)
data = PHI/np.pi
norm = plt.Normalize(vmin=data.min(), vmax=data.max())


# use Light Source
ls = LightSource(0, 0)
# create rgb shade
rgb = ls.shade(x, cmap=cm.Wistia, vert_exag=0.1, blend_mode='soft')
# blend shade
bsl = ls.blend_hsv(rgb, np.expand_dims(x*0.8, 2))
# plot surface
surface = ax.plot_surface(x, y, z, cstride=1, rstride=1, facecolors=bsl,
                       linewidth=0, antialiased=False, shade=False)


plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]